# Killing a cohomology class in a manifold by taking out a submanifold representing its Poincaré-dual

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, 4-manifolds

Let $M$ be an oriented $n$-manifold, $\alpha \in H^k(M;R)$ a cohomology class so that its Poincaré-dual $a\in H_{n-k}(M;R)$ is represented by an embedded $(n-k)$-manifold $F$.

**Question:** Is the restriction of $\alpha$ to $M-F$ always trivial?

In particular, I am interested in the case where $n=4$, $k=2$, $R=\mathbb{Z}/2$ and $\alpha$ is the second Stiefel-Whitney class of $M$. This case is used in the book *4-manifolds and Kirby Calculus* by Gompf and Stipsicz (p.187). If the Statement in my Question is false, how would I try to prove this special case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, let us fix a cohomology class $\beta \in H^i (M)$ and denote its dual homology class in $H_{n-i}(M)$ by $b$. Poincare-Lefschetz duality allows us to identify $H^*(M - F)$ with $\bar{H}_{n-*}(M/F)$ (the topological quotient). There is an interaction between the Poincare duality of $M$ and the Poincare-Lefschetz duality of $(M-F)$, namely the restriction $\iota^* (\beta)$ is Poincare dual to $q_*(b)$, the pushforward of $b$ under the quotient map. If the class $\beta$ is Poincare dual to a homology class, this has a very geometric proof via intersection theory for noncompact manifolds. If $\beta$ is a general cohomology class, the easiest proof of this is likely via the Thom isomorphism theorem.

Specializing to the case $\beta =\alpha$, we see that the Poincare-Lefshcetz dual of $\iota^* (\alpha)$ is the image of $[F]$ under the quotient map collapsing $F$ to a point, i.e. is $0$. Since Poincare-Lefschetz duality is an isomorphism, this implies that the restriction of $\alpha$ to $M-F$ is 0.

Comment: Thank you! I am not familiar with the version of Poincaré-Lefschetz duality you mentioned, I only know the version where you take out a compact subset in the homology and take the quotient in the homology (e.g. Bredon VI.8.3). Do you know where I can find this version?

Comment: @Christian This precise formulation follows from Atiyah duality for manifolds with boundary. The reason the quotient can occur on either side is that Atiyah duality is a statement about the Spanier-Whitehead dual of a manifold. One may apply either cohomology or homology to this statement and get versions of Poincare duality, in one the quotient will appear next to the homology, and in the other it will appear next to the cohomology.

Answer (score 1):

As Connor pointed out, the answer to my question is positive. I just wanted to write down an easy proof with precise references.

Let $\nu(F)$ be a tubular neighborhood of $F$. We apply Poincaré-Lefschetz duality in the form of [Bredon, VI.8.4] to $M$ and $M-\nu(F)$ to obtain a commutative diagram of the following form.

\begin{array}
  0& & H^k(M;R) &\xrightarrow{i^*}& H^k(M\setminus \nu(F);R)  \\
            &&\downarrow&&\downarrow\\
   H_{n-k}(\nu(F);R) & \xrightarrow{j_*} & H_{n-k}(M;R) & \xrightarrow{u}                & {H_{n-k}(M,\nu(F);R)}                       
\end{array}

The vertical maps are isomorphisms induced by Poincaré duality and I will denote them by PD. A class $\alpha\in H^k(M)$ which is Poincaré-dual to $j_*[F]$ evidently maps to zero under $i^*$ as the diagram commutes and $u(j_*[F])$ is trivial.